# Finding Velocity and Distance Formula from Integral of Acceleration

Tags: integration

Working on a homework problem here for integration that has two parts:

(1) Suppose that an object of mass m is initially held at rest, then is released and acted upon by a constant gravitational acceleration g = 9.8 m/s2. Using integral calculus, derive expressions for the speed v(t) (units m/s) and distance x(t) (units m) traveled by the object t seconds after its release. (Assume that the gravitational force is the only force acting on the object.)

I know that eventually I should have:

v(t) = 9.8t + C

and then x(t) = 4.9t^2 + Ct + D

But how does one go about solving for the values of the constants?

The next question involves the answer to this one so maybe those answers are actually correct and I use them with the values given in the next problem? Here it is:

(2) If an object of mass m is dropped from the top of the Burj Khalifa tower in Dubai which stands 829.8 m tall, how long will it take to reach the ground according to the equations of motion you developed in Question 1? What is its speed when it hits the ground?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that the object is initially at rest you can solve both equations for C and D at t=0.